# Javascript - refresh iframe not working

Tags: javascript

I have search for multiple post regarding the same topic but those posts are few years ago.

I did tried with below code but still not working:

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').src = document.getElementById('iframeid').src
```

or

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.location.reload()
```

or

```
document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.location.reload(true)
```

My iframe code is:

```
<iframe src="./storefront.html" height="100%" width="100%" id="iframeid"></iframe>
```

My JS code is:

```
function ThemeA(){
    var PreHeader = document.getElementById("Pheader");
    var PreBody = document.getElementById("PBody");
    var PreProduct1 = document.getElementById("ThemeProductList1");
    var PreProduct2 = document.getElementById("ThemeProductList2");
    var PreProduct3 = document.getElementById("ThemeProductList3");
    var PreProduct4 = document.getElementById("ThemeProductList4");
    var PreProductStyle1 = document.getElementById("prod1");
    var PreProductStyle2 = document.getElementById("prod2");
    var PreProductStyle3 = document.getElementById("prod3");
    var PreProductStyle4 = document.getElementById("prod4");

    PreHeader.className = "PreviewHeader Theme-A-Header-Color Theme-A-Font-Color";
    PreBody.className = "PreviewBody Theme-A-Font-Family";
    PreProduct1.className = " Theme-A-Product ";
    PreProduct2.className = " Theme-A-Product ";
    PreProduct3.className = " Theme-A-Product ";
    PreProduct4.className = " Theme-A-Product ";
    PreProductStyle1.className = "Theme-A-ProductStyle";
    PreProductStyle2.className = "Theme-A-ProductStyle";
    PreProductStyle3.className = "Theme-A-ProductStyle";
    PreProductStyle4.className = "Theme-A-ProductStyle";
    document.getElementById('iframeid').contentWindow.location.reload()
}
```

All classes been set accordingly, but the iframe refresh part just not working.

Comment: can you refresh from console?

Comment: i don see any error from the console..

Comment: do you see any get "requests" being rendered when running from console?   watch this screen when running from console to see what is happening.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor .

Comment: when open the page, the [network monitor] did listing whatever thing that require to resolve a page, it details down by the current page section and the <iframe> page section. But when i click on the function, nothing changes in there(not sure how it suppose to be rendered)...